# Resolving dependencies in express server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having some trouble resolving dependencies on my express server.

Here is my project structure

```
Calculator
--dist
----app
-------calculator.js
-------server.js
--node_modules
--src
----app
--------calculator.js
--------server.js
----public
--------calculator.css
--------calculator.html
----.babelrc
----.gitignore
----package.json
```

Here is my server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./src/public/calculator.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../src/app/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(__dirname);
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

The reason I have a dist folder and a src folder is because I am compiling my JS from ES6 from the src folder to ES5 within the app folder using Babel.

However, when I launch my node server, my html is not able to load the css file and JS file. I am using these paths to load each respectively from the calculator.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./calculator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./calculator.js"></script>
```

I am sure I am missing something about the way files are served on a localhost. Would appreciate the error being pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this worked for me although I'm not a 100% sure why exactly.

I set my express static file delivery to the following

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../src/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

My `__dirname` was shown to be `Calculator/dist/app` so changing the src attributes for the CSS and JS in the HTML file to this worked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./calculator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./calculator.js"></script>
```

I am assuming this works because I set my express static folder to look inside the `/src/public` folder and since my current directory was the `/dist/app` folder, I could serve the JS file directly from there?

Comment: That's perfect. You're now serving up all the files in `src/public` and all the files in `dist/app`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like on line 9 in `server.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../src/app/public'));
```

you're going from the `app` folder up to `src`, up to the root, back down into `src`, back into `app`, and then trying to go down into `public`. However by your project structure diagram, `public` isn't inside `app` but rather beside it. You'd want something more like `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../public'));` In addition, I'd recommend using the `path` module that's built into Node. It'll make sure you don't have mistakes in path creation.

EDIT: Sorry, that was incorrect. I didn't see that you were transpiling your server code as well. You'll want to use these lines, which should fix both:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../src/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

This is assuming you run the `server.js` file present in `dist/app` and not the one in `src/app`.

Comment: That worked for the CSS file. But for some reason, I still can't seem to serve the JS file.

Comment: Change to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/calculator.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these ...

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/./src/app/public'));

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname} + '/./src/app/public')); // __dirname doesn't include the ending back slash, I think?

The first will always look in your static directory, and the second will look in your static directory for '/' and below. See https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use for more.

And then ...

Change your HTML so the src attributes will be '/calculator.css', etc